# permission issue for selenium webdriver/geckodriver on gcp jupyterlab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, gcp-notebook

I am trying to test run a crawler on GCP jupyter lab before choosing the best solution on GCP. However I am having issues with the webdriver for selenium saying there is a permission issue as per below. I have set up my instance as per documentation on GCP. Tried to tweak here and there but still didnt work. Is this a Notebook issue as it is still on beta or its an issue with the firewall/proxy settings?

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/jupyter/chromedriver.exe")
print(browser.capabilities['version'])
print(browser.version)
```

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/jupyter/geckodriver.exe")
print(browser.capabilities['version'])
print(browser.version)
```

WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions.

Comment: for the last error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293651/how-to-fix-error-message-chromedriver-exe-executable-may-have-wrong-permissio) says that this might be due to a platform and chromedriver format mismatch.  So I would go as a configuration issue

Comment: webdriver configuration on my jupyter notebook or my network?

Comment: In addition to @José Soní comment, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148872/webdrivers-executable-may-have-wrong-permissions-please-see-https-sites-goo) is a post where the last error is discussed for Windows. Is this your case? Does this help?